# Desigining problem in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am displaying a image (image size is 90px width,90px height) and below that i displaying title of the image in data list control (horizontal display). i used table (tags) in source code.
the image and title will display dynamically from database. my problem is when title is too long it is disturbing my design, when title is too long it should come down, the title should same size as the picture if it is too long it come down in second line.

for example the below is a image and below that image title

```
     --------------
    |             |
    |             |
    |             |
    |             |
    |             |
    |_____________|
    surya sasidhar rao
```

the above image title is too long. the letters "rao" should come in second line.

```
    --------------
    |             |
    |             |
    |             |
    |             |
    |             |
    |_____________|
    surya sasidhar 
    rao
```

this is the desing i want. how can i get it.
this is my source code

'  CommandName="Play" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("VideoName")+"|"+Eval("videoid")+","+Eval("username")%>' Width ="90px" Height ="90px" />
                       
                    
                    
                       
                          '  CommandName="title" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("VideoName")+"|"+Eval("videoid")+","+Eval("username")%>'>
                       
                    
                    
                      
                         '>
                      
                    
                    
                      
                        '>

[alt text http://c:%5C%5Cmyimage](http://c:%5C%5Cmyimage)

Comment: I am using table like
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <asp:image>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <asp:label text="title of the image">
   </td>
 </tr>

Comment: in you tube how they can maintain the image alignment. if the title of the video is too long even though the image and its title align is equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the great things about web development is that the source code is available for all to see, look at, and take inspiration from. Using tools like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) in FireFox or the Developer Tools in Internet Explorer 8 make this even easier.

Open the page that you want to emulate, and inspect the code around the areas in question. You'll see that YouTube isn't using tables, but divs and css.

```
<div class="feedmodule-body grid-view">
  <!-- "Video display module" starts here, with the Clear Left class -->
  <div class="clearL">
    <div  class="video-cell" style="width:24.5%">
      <div class="video-entry yt-uix-hovercard">
        <a class="video-thumb-120" href="/path-to-video"><img src="thumbnail" />
          </a>
        <div class="video-main-content video-title-one-line">
          <div  class="video-title ">
            <div class="video-short-title">
              <a href="/path-to-video">The shortened title goes here, but still
                wraps...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="video-long-title">
              <a href="/path-to-video">The full title goes here, and would still
                wraps when it's shown.</a>
              <div class="video-logos"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="video-description">Description</div>
          [...]
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Repeat from the div with clearL -->
</div>
```

Then you look at the declarations for those classes, and see how they all fit together:

```
.clearL {
  clear:left;
}
.grid-view .video-cell {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.feedmodule-data .grid-view .video-entry {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.grid-view .video-entry {
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
.video-thumb-120 {
  border:3px double #999999;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:72px;
  width:120px;
}
.grid-view .video-main-content {
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-top:2px;
}
/* Etc, etc - I feel dirty posting the whole thing here ;)
   take a look at the source for yourself to see the rest */
```

Comment: ok nice i will check and let u inform you Mr. Zhaph-ben duguid

Answer (score 1):

You should set the width of the `<td>` of the image and the label to 90px or maybe a little bit wider like so:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="imageHolder"><asp:Image /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="captionHolder"><asp:Label /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td.imageHolder, td.captionHolder
{
    width:95px;
}
```

Comment: ya it is working fine. but the image is move up side other images r uniform alignment but the image which has long title is move up side not in a correct alignment

Comment: in you tube how they can align this problem. image and title is in the same alignment even the title is too long or too short

Comment: Try giving both cells a vertical-align:top; in CSS.

Comment: ok i will try and let u inform Mr. Kristof Claes thank you for response

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot of the problem and some of your HTML/CSS code?

Comment: but how can i send screen shot